# How can I optimize Huffman Decoding?

Tags: java, huffman-code

So I've been trying to decode using huffman, and I have this working function but it has horrible time and space complexity. What I've been doing so far is reading each byte, getting each bit and adding it to the currentBitString. I then reversed the string, and added it to a huge string which bascially contains all the byte data for the file. After that, I would trace the giant string and look for the Huffman code and then if its a match, i would write to file. This code takes about 60 seconds to decode a 200kb, which is very bad, but I'm not really sure how to improve it? I know I could for starters, write more than one byte to the file at a time, but it didn't seem to improve the time when I tried?

```
         public static void decode(File f) throws Exception {

    BufferedInputStream fin = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
    int i = f.getName().lastIndexOf('.');
    String extension="txt";
    String newFileName=f.getName().substring(0, i)+extension;
    File nf = new File(newFileName);
    BufferedOutputStream fw = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(nf));
    int c;
    byte bits;
    byte current;
    String currentBitString="";
    String bitString="";
    //read each byte from file, reverse it, add to giant bitString
    //reads ALL BYTES
    while( (c=fin.read())!=-1 ) {
        current=(byte) c;
        currentBitString="";
        bits=0;
        for(int q=0;q<8;q++) {
            bits=getBit(current,q);
            currentBitString+=bits;
        }
        StringBuilder bitStringReverse=new StringBuilder(currentBitString);
        bitString+=bitStringReverse.reverse().toString();
    }
    currentBitString="";
    boolean foundCode=false;
    for(int j=0;j<bitString.length();j++) {
        currentBitString+=bitString.charAt(j);
        for(int k=0;k<nodes.length;k++) {
            //nodes is an array of huffman nodes which contains the the byte 
            //data and the huffman codes for each byte
            if(nodes[k].code.compareTo(currentBitString.trim())==0) {
                fw.write(nodes[k].data);    
                foundCode=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(foundCode) {
            currentBitString="";
            foundCode=false;
        }

    }
    fw.flush();
    fw.close();
    fin.close();

}
```

here's the gitBit function

```
        public static byte getBit(byte ID, int position) {
        // return cretin bit in selected byte
        return (byte) ((ID >> position) & 1);
        }
```

here's the data members of the HuffmanNode class (the nodes array is a array of HuffmanNodes)

```
       public class HuffmanNode{
       byte data;
       int repetitions;
       String code;
       HuffmanNode right;
       HuffmanNode left;
       }
```

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/efficient-huffman-coding-for-sorted-input-greedy-algo-4/

Comment: You may have a very inefficiently coded implementation but complexity doesn't say anything about that. It's still O(n) time and from a quick scan, O(n) space too. You're asking the wrong question, you can't xhsnde it's complexity but you want to optimize the code. And the question is likely too broad for SO.

Comment: I have really no plan what your code is doing. But I observe that it's super heavy regarding memory allocation: For each character you read, you allocate a *StringBuilder* instance, *toString()* allocates a *String* instance and `+=` allocates another 9 *String* instance. There is tremendous potential for optimization.

Comment: See https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1643. Also, why build the bitstring left-to-right and then reverse it (thus using up more memory and taking up more time) when you can simply build it the right way to begin with, using `for (int q=7;q>=0;q--)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the String concatination `+=` with `StringBuilder`. This allocates less objects and puts less load on the garbage collector.

```
int c;
StringBuilder bitString = new StringBuilder();
//read each byte from file, reverse it, add to giant bitString
//reads ALL BYTES
while ((c = fin.read()) != -1) {
    byte current = (byte) c;
    StringBuilder currentBitString = new StringBuilder();
    for (int q = 0; q < 8; q++) {
        byte bits = getBit(current, q);
        currentBitString.append(bits);
    }
    bitString.append(currentBitString.reverse());
}
```

Instead of putting the codes and data into an array `nodes` you should use a `HashMap` here. You are comparing the code by iterating over the whole array until you find the right match. On average that are `n/2` calls to `String#equals()` per item. With a `HashMap` you reduce this to ~1.

Fill your map with the data for the codes as keys.

```
Map<String, Integer> nodes = new HashMap<>();
nodes.put(code, data);
```

Access the data from the map

```
boolean foundCode = false;
for (int j = 0; j < bitString.length(); j++) {
    currentBitString.append(bitString.charAt(j));
    Integer data = nodes.get(currentBitString.toString().trim());
    if (data != null) {
        fw.write(data);
        foundCode = true;
    }
    if (foundCode) {
        currentBitString = new StringBuilder();
        foundCode = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the break statement just get out of the entire loop and not check if the code is found?

Comment: I tried it out and put the break statement in the second loop but it didn't work, there seems to be an infinite loop somewhere

Comment: The break statement is no longer needed as the HashMap removed the second loop to iterate over the array. Updated the code. If the code is not 100% right I think you still get the idea.

Comment: I get the idea and I've implemented it, but the time hasn't really gone down for some reason, it still takes a minute to decode a 200kb file.

Comment: @TheHaruWhoCodes: In that case, you should profile your program e.g. with visualVM. This can tell you in which method you spent the most time.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't read the whole thing into memory. Process your codes as they are encountered. Read enough bits to decode the next code, decode it, retain the unused bits for the subsequent code, repeat.
2. Don't use strings of characters to represent bits, where you are representing one bit per character. Use bits to represent bits. The shift, and, and or operators are what you should be using. You would have an integer as a bit buffer, with all the bits you need to decode the next code.
3. Don't do a search over all code lengths, and inside that a linear search of all codes to find your code! I would be hard pressed to come up with a slower approach. You should use a tree descent or table lookup for decoding. If you generate a [canonical Huffman code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_Huffman_code) in the first place, there is an easy lookup approach that can be implemented. See [puff.c](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/contrib/puff/puff.c) for an example. The textbook approach (which is slower than what puff.c does) is to build the same Huffman tree on the receiving end, and go down that tree bit-by-bit until you get to a symbol. Emit the symbol and repeat.

You should be able to process 200K of compressed input in a few milliseconds on a single core of a modern processor.